# What statistical test to use

Tags: experiment-design, difference-in-difference, methodology

I want to carry out a study but I don’t know which statistical method to use for analysing the results.

I have two buildings (say, houses A and B) and I keep daily records of some quantitative variable Y on both houses. I want to apply a treatment or intervention in house B and see if it has a meaningful effect over Y, using records of house A as control.

Before applying the treatment, I already know that house A tends to have a lower Y than house B, and I think I should somehow adjust or control by this difference,  but I don’t know how to correctly do it. Besides that, because of the time of the year, I expect the values of Y to increase on both houses.

I’ll illustrate the situation with some figures. Before the intervention, I have $n_1$ records of variable Y on house A with an average of 35; and another $n_1$ observations on house B with an average of 54. After the intervention, I have $n_2$ observations on house A with an average of 48 and another $n_2$ observations on house B with an average of 72.

| Y mean | Before intervention | After intervention |
| --- | --- | --- |
| House A | 35 | 48 |
| House B | 54 | 72 |

My questions are:

1. What statistical technique should I use to determine if the intervention has a significant effect over the outcome variable Y?
2. Since I already know that before the intervention there’s a significant difference in the average of Y in both houses, should I somehow adjust or control for it? If so, how?

For what I’ve been reading, I think this is a [quasi-experimental design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-experiment) with non-equivalent control group, since there is no random assignation.
I’ve also been reading about [difference in differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences) but I have concerns about it since my data is somehow temporal (I have daily records, and variable Y is definitely affected by the time of the year).

Thank you for your answers!

**Edit 1:**

Before the intervention, I have measured $n_1$=13 days on both houses, so I have a total of 26 observations $Y_{A_1},..., Y_{A_{13}}, Y_{B_1},...,Y_{B_{13}} $.
After the intervention I have recorded $n_1$=10 daily observations on each house: $Y_{A_{14}},..., Y_{A_{23}}, Y_{B_{14}},...,Y_{B_{23}} $.

Comment: Welcome. How many records do you have on each household, in each time period, roughly speaking?

Comment: You'll need to clarify the data collection process a little bit more, as @ThomasBilach suggests, but you seem to be describing an interrupted time series design with a comparison group. ITSA were first described by Campbell and Stanley in 1966 and there have been a lot of work on this kind of design and its analysis. Good luck.

Comment: ANCOVA could also be better in terms of power than DID if autocorrelation is low. Seasonality is not inherently an issue with DID if you expect that the trends would be parallel between the houses in the absence of treatment.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @ThomasBilach, I have 13 records before the intervention in each building, and 10 after the intervention in each one of them.

Comment: This sounds like the "paired watershed" design.